# Create script to run multiple commands with variable in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So basically, I'm trying to streamline a process where I run an executable script to update remote devices that are connected to my server. Initially, I had a few devices that I would update, but it's gotten to the point where it's over 40 and it takes forever to update them all manually. I'd like to create a script to update them all at the same time using the executable, but the only thing I can't figure out is how to include a variable in the script that I can input on the command line, as the `version_number` has to be manually inputted.

Right now, it looks something like this :

`./updater-app device_number version_number`

What I've been doing is just copying and pasting a long command to somewhat streamline the process, however, with over 40 devices to update, it's somewhat tedious, and will only get worse with remote devices to update in the future

`./updater-app device1 version20 & ./updater-app device2 version20 & ./updater-app device3 version20 &` .... and so on.

Since the device numbers all stay the same, basically I just want to create a shell script that allows me update all of them at the same time, but input a `version_number` variable on the command line, as that changes every time a new version of the device software comes out.

Comment: It's completely possible, just write a script that takes a version number as an argument and pass that as an argument to `updater-app`.

Comment: Use **GNU Parallel**. Put a list of your devices, one per line, in a file called `devices.txt` then run `parallel -a devices.txt ./updater-app {} version20`

Comment: Awesome! I'll give GNU parallel a try.

Comment: Try it with `parallel --dry-run` at first so you can see what it will do without actually doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can create a loop and run the whole  update script one by one. It will run parallel, as it's running in background

```
listOfDevices=("device1" "device2" "device3" ....)
version=$1

for device in "${listOfDevices[@]}"
do
   ./updater-app $device $version &
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work pretty well. However, is there any way to silence the output? It seems like the & isn't working for some reason.

Comment: You can redirect output like this. ./updater-app $device $version > /dev/null 2>&1 &